# AttributeError: 'Flags' object has no attribute 'c_contiguous'

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, classification, knn

I am following Hands On Machine Learning Book by Aurélien Géron and running in to the following error.

Code:

```
y_train_large = (y_train.astype("int") >= 7)
y_train_odd = (y_train.astype("int") % 2 == 1)
y_multilabel = np.c_[y_train_large, y_train_odd]

#model
knn_clf = KNeighborsClassifier()
knn_clf.fit(X_train, y_multilabel)

y_train_knn_pred = cross_val_predict(knn_clf, X_train, y_multilabel, cv=3)
```

The last line produces the following error:

```
{
AttributeError: 'Flags' object has no attribute 'c_contiguous'"
}
```

Since I am following the book, I expected this code to work. I have tried solutions from Google Bard and Claude AI chatbots but with no success.

Comment: Here’s the link to the python notebook. Scroll to the end for the error-producing code.
[MNIST python notebook](https://github.com/acratophorux/python-playground/blob/main/HOML/MNIST.ipynb)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There seems to be a [bug report](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/issues/26768) for this in Scikit-learn `1.3.0` (although it seems to have been [fixed](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/pull/26772) in the nightly builds). Try downgrading to version `1.2.2`:

```
pip uninstall scikit-learn
pip install scikit-learn==1.2.2
```

Comment: I have tried downgrading to version `1.2.2` but still getting the same error.

Comment: @ACX I can't reproduce the error. Runs fine on colab: https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1cRxdoreM2Uw8PRdkD1WkjuEbvSz8FUXA?usp=sharing

Comment: Note that colab's scikit-learn is `1.2.2`.

Comment: Issue resolved with `1.2.2` version (I had downgraded but then subsequently chose wrong python env which still had `1.3.0` installed.)

Thank you for the support. Highly appreciated.